# how to iterate by loop with values in function using python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, automation

I want to pass values using loop one by one in function using python.Values are stored in dataframe.

```
def eam(A,B):
    y=A +" " +B
    return y
```

Suppose I pass the values of `A` as country and `B` as capital .
Dataframe `df` is

```
country                   capital
India                     New Delhi
Indonesia                 Jakarta
Islamic Republic of Iran  Tehran
Iraq                      Baghdad
Ireland                   Dublin
```

How can I get value using loop

```
0   India New Delhi
1   Indonesia Jakarta
2   Islamic Republic of Iran Tehran
3   Iraq Baghdad
4   Ireland Dublin
```

Comment: If your data frame a Pandas DataFrame?

Comment: If you really want a loop, you could use `apply()` like this: `df.apply(lambda x: eam(x['country'], x['capital']), axis=1)`

Comment: Why was this tagged as regex?

Comment: yes,dataframe is pandas DataFrame

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, just use the following syntax to get a new column in the dataframe. No need to write code to loop over the rows. However, if you must loop, df.iterrows() returns or df.itertuples() provide nice functionality to accomplish similar objectives.

```
>>> df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t')
>>> df.head()
                    country    capital
0                     India  New Delhi
1                 Indonesia    Jakarta
2  Islamic Republic of Iran     Tehran
3                      Iraq    Baghdad
4                   Ireland     Dublin
>>> df.columns
Index(['country', 'capital'], dtype='object')
>>> df['both'] = df['country'] + " " + df['capital']
>>> df.head()
                    country    capital                             both
0                     India  New Delhi                  India New Delhi
1                 Indonesia    Jakarta                Indonesia Jakarta
2  Islamic Republic of Iran     Tehran  Islamic Republic of Iran Tehran
3                      Iraq    Baghdad                     Iraq Baghdad
4                   Ireland     Dublin                   Ireland Dublin
```

Comment: The values need to be passed in function eam. Dont use directly dataframe